# End-user feedback interview for an early stage prototype

Tags: gui-design, surveys, user-feedback

Are the following questions appropriate to garner feedback from an early stage prototype? If not, what questions would be more appropriate:

For the individual:

[image]

For the business:

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing these surveys will be more useful to marketing than the UX team. I wouldn't know what actions to take from the results you get. You might consider doing some usability testing, which will reveal where users have trouble and where they find delight. Just 5-7 subjects will reveal a lot about your design.

Comment: I would like to carry out usability testing. But I am likely to be working with +700 participants which will be spaced out geographically, and need a way to process a large set of responses in a cost efficient way.

Comment: Your research method should be determined by what sort of results you want, and what sort of actions you want to take. If you're looking for a marketing direction, then surveys might be the right way to go. If you're looking for usability improvements, then a small usability test will do it. (There are remote, unmoderated usability services out there like usertesting.com where you can get lots more subjects, but no direct observations.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rating scale questions don't seem useful, unless you'll have an opportunity to follow up in more detail. Imagine that that respondents rated the app 1.5/5 on "features." How would you act on that information?

The "With regard to..." questions are very jargony. Imagine how a user would phrase these questions (e.g,. "Do you have suggestions about how to make the app look nicer?", "How could we make the app easier to use?")

A more fundamental issue with those questions is that you're asking the users to do design. Their job is to use the app and tell you what they experienced, not to decide how to act on it. Ask them for *specifics* about what they enjoyed, what was difficult, and what surprised them. Then use that information to decide how you can make the app a better fit for their needs.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Do you reckon something something similar to this would work for question 1.1: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7Y7q9.png

Comment: Those are better, and you could probably cut down the list to just a few that are important to you. Still, make sure you gather specifics -- otherwise it's difficult to know what to do with any negative feedback.